# Passing an array to another array method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oop, c#-4.0

I need to create 2 methods. Method 1 (CreateArray) shall allow the user to enter the length of an array they would like to create and then enter the value for each element. Method 2 (PrintArray) prints the array created in Method 1.

Both methods work fine on a standalone basis. However, I don't know how to pass CreateArray method to PrintArray method.

```
class Calculation
{
    public int[] CreateArray (int a)
    {
        int count = 1;
        int[] CreateArray = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < CreateArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write($"{count}.) Enter a value - ");
            int userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            CreateArray[i] = userInput;
            count++;
        }
        return CreateArray;
    }

    public void PrintArray(int[] numbers)
    {
        int elementNum = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{elementNum}.) {numbers[i]}");
            elementNum++;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter the Length of an array you would like to create: ");
        int arrayLength = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Calculation calc = new Calculation();
        calc.CreateArray(arrayLength);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass the `CreateArray` method to the `PrintArray` method? Maybe you mean you want to pass the array which is created to the `PrintArray` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the results of "calc.CreateArray(arrayLength);" in a local variable and pass it to PrintArray():

```
int[] newArray = calc.CreateArray(arrayLength);
calc.PrintArray(newArray);
```

Comment: Side Note: You should probably either change your Calculation class to store the passed values as a proberty inside that instance or make CreateArray and PrintArray static and call them directly via "Calculation.CreateArray(len)" and "Calculation.PrintArray(arr)"

Comment: SebRut: And every time you want a new array you have create an instance of `Calculation` instead of an `int[]`. Guess that's not a good idea. And we haven't started talking about testability .

Comment: @MightyBadaboom that's why I also suggested to make the methods static, which imo is the right way to do this kind auf task.

Comment: @SebBut that's why I mentioned testability. You can't mock static methods as far as I know for example. And if you want more then one array you still have to instantiate x instances of the calculation class instead of x arrays if you store the variables in the Claculation class. That's why I would solve it like you wrote in the answer and not like you wrote in your comment.

Comment: Thankyou. I am new to programming so I was just learning how to create methods and call them in the main method.